# Maximum cloud computing utilization - pay for computing, not idle time

Tags: azure, cloud, iaas, azure-batch

I have one big task to do every day, with no need to scale, that takes about 30 minutes and is DB, processor and memory intensive.
This means actual 16h/month of computation time.

- WebJobs require constantly running WebSite 744h/month
- WebRole is also constantly running 744h/month
- Azure Batch - suited for scaled storage input - storage output
  processing (or that is how I understand it)

Stopped cloud service still cost you. Setting instance count to 0 is not available. And paying for 728h/month unused computation time looks like madness. Only thing I can imagine is automatic deployment of cloud service every day and automatic deletion of deployment once task is finished, but this also looks like madness.
Are there any options for this scenario in Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud service will be charged continuously until the deployment is deleted. Yes you can delete it every day and redeploy...

Azure VMs in Stopped (Deallocated) status, does not incur any charge. You can shut them down in portal or by script when you don't need them.

I think there is a large difference in billing if you only use it 62h/month. Would you consider switch this deployment to VM? WorkerRole and VMs can be placed on the same subnet, they can still connect to each other.

Comment: Yes, VM can be an alternative, however from development side it is still a workaround and not different from deploying-underplaying a worker role.